# Grizzly 2.3.11 - CLStaticHttpHandler - cannot read index.html under resource folder when packed in a jar

Tags: maven, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I want to host static web pages in a jar. So I used Maven to pack the java project containing a folder having a index.html web page. My code:

```
server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, resourceConfig, start);
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler();new CLStaticHttpHandler(Server.class.getClassLoader(), myfolder/), /mysite)
```

When I access `http://localhost:8080/mysite/` in IDE, the handler is able to read index.html. But if I use mvn package and run the jar file, `http://localhost:8080/mysite/` doesn't work, unless I specify `http://localhost:8080/mysite/index.html` in a browser to make it work. The web page folder is under `src/main/resources`, and it is under the root path when opening the jar.

Thank you so much!

Added: To reproduce this, you can create a Maven project by writing a pom.xml and put something like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>simple-service</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>     
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
      <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <version>1.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.6</jersey.version>
        <grizzly.version>2.3.11</grizzly.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

and create a server like:

```
final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();
        rc.register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()), true));
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(new URI(BASE_URI), rc);

        server.getServerConfiguration()
            .addHttpHandler(new CLStaticHttpHandler(ServletSimple.class.getClassLoader(), "statichtmlfolder/"), "/ui/" );

        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at " + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.shutdown();
```

`statichtmlfolder` is a folder containing all the `index.html` file under `/src/main/resources/`. we are using Jersey2 here. And use `mvn package` to package the code to a jar file, go to `target` folder, then run `java -cp dependency/*:api-server-1.0.26-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.Main`. We can see the `statichtmlfolder` is under the root directory in the jar file.

Comment: Can you pls. share the testcase and describe how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I think it is highly because `CLStaticHttpHandler` is not able to find resoruces in a jar file even though we can see it tries to add a `/index.html` after `docRoot`. You can refer to the edited contents of my question. Thank you for you attention.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is fixed in Grizzly 2.3.13
https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1687

Comment: I've spent a few hours and figured that this is the issue - upgraded and it fixed it instantly